# combine multiple values in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have the data in the following format (in csv file):

```
 id, review
 1, the service was great!
 1, staff was friendly.
 2, nice location
 2, but the place was not clean
 2, the motel was okay
 3, i wouldn't stay there next time
 3, do not stay there
```

I would like to change the data to the following format:

```
 1, the service was great! staff was friendly. 
 2, nice location but the place was not clean the motel was okay
 3, i wouldn't stay there next time do not stay there
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the matching criteria since the last line does not start with `1` but is appended to the lines before?

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: @albert I corrected the output.

Comment: @tobias_k I corrected the typo. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for grouping consecutive entries that have the same number.

```
import itertools, operator, csv
with open("test.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    next(reader) # skip header line
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
        print key, ' '.join(g[1] for g in group)
```

Output:

```
1  the service was great!  staff was friendly.
2  nice location  but the place was not clean  the motel was okay
3  i wouldn't stay there next time  do not stay there
```

Note: The code for reading the file is assuming that it's an actual CSV file, with `,` delimiter:

```
id, review
1, the service was great!
...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.